# angular 10 throwing an error "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Using new features from Typescript "export * as ns Syntax" causes angular to throw this error. I tried playing around with the tsconfig.base.json file by changing module to es2015 and esnext but each one throws a different error of its own.

I am using angular 10.0.14 with typescript 3.9.6.

The "export * as ns Syntax" was introduced in typescript 3.8 => https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Example syntax:

```
export * as AuthLoginActions from "./login.actions";
```

Comment: Have you found solution?